# SQL - many to many table wont work

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**#1005 - Can't create table 'ass1 lol.management' (errno: 150) (Details...)**

i'm having the above error returned when i try create this many to many table

trying to create a many to many table between employees and supervisors, not error is returned when i make the supervisor and employee tables. but when i go to create my management table i get the above error.

these are my create table statements

employee table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (

    emp_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    yr_ser INT(4),
    status VARCHAR(30),
    emp_name VARCHAR(30),
    emp_gen VARCHAR(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)
);
```

supervisor  Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS supervisor (
    sup_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    sup_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    gen INT(4),
    dep_id INT(4),

    PRIMARY KEY (sup_id),
    INDEX (dep_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (dep_id)
        REFERENCES department(dep_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT    
);
```

**but then when i go to create this table i get the error**

management Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS management (
    emp_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    sup_id INT(4) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, sup_id),
    INDEX (emp_id),
    INDEX (sup_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
        REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

    FOREIGN KEY (sup_id)
        REFERENCES supervisor(act_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: the devil, as they say, is in the details. or in other words, you should include the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your may-to-many table references a field `act_id` in the `supervisor` table, but no such field is defined. Should be `sup_id` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS management (
emp_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
sup_id INT(4) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, sup_id),
INDEX (emp_id),
INDEX (sup_id),

FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
    REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

FOREIGN KEY (sup_id)
    REFERENCES supervisor(sup_id) -- Here
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```